Deterministically create a collection with 100 elements for worst case of Shell Sort algorithm
Two questions.

Can I deterministically generate an array with 100 elements (1,2,...,100) that is the worst case for the shell sort algorithm?
If no, why? Why is there only stochastic way?

What I have tried

Reversing the steps of the algorithm does work, as h=1 sorts the collection at the last step.
When I exclude it and put h=4 as the last, then again the the array is sorted for every 4th element.

def generate_worst_case_shell_sort(n, gaps):
    # Start with a sorted array
    array = list(range(1, n + 1))
    
    for gap in reversed(gaps):
        # Process groups defined by the gap
        for i in range(gap):
            group = array[i::gap]
            # Reverse sort each group
            group.sort(reverse=True)
            array[i::gap] = group
    
    return array

# Example usage
n = 100
gaps = [1, 4, 13, 40]
worst_case_array = generate_worst_case_shell_sort(n, gaps)
print(worst_case_array)


Writing a math formula for moving elements based on the current h and that proved to be quite tricky. I for example realized that for h=40 the collection of 100 elements is being split into chunks of 20 elements. And they swap symmetrically. When I moved to h=13, it turned out that swapping is not anymore that straightforward.

Algorithm
Here is one of possible implementations.
def shell_sort(A):
    N = len(A)
    h = 1
    while h < N // 3:
        h = h * 3 + 1
    while h >= 1:
        for i in range(h, N):
            for j in range(i, h-1, -h):
                if less(A[j], A[j - h]):
                    exch(A, j, j - h)
        h //= 3

Context
Rene Argento suggests that authors are hinting at stochastic approach with a random generation.
The 2.1.19 problem comes from Algorithms (4th ed) by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
Related
Similar questions are questioning - here and here - the complexity and I am only interested in the array with 100 elements generation/creation.

You can test your approach for a smaller example where you can compare the concrete runtime with the one of all permutations of the input.

I like you idea.
I have tried that.
I got for 10 the following results:
Total permutations: 3628800.
Comparisons: 37.
Number of permutations that have max comparisons(37): 192.
So there is no single array but a pool.

I can't see how you determine the worst case of 37 for shellsort where n = 10. What I mean is what set of gaps did you use and are they the best set for n = 10?
I have found that the best set of gaps where n = 10 produces a worst case of 35 comparisons - which is why I ask.
But perhaps the original question wasn't concerned with the best set of gaps, maybe any set was ok to use?
